# Heisenberg picture and time dependence of a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, coherent-states

I'll try to give you a quick background of what I'm doing, then the question will come: I'm studying an EFT where a coherent state of a scalar field $\Phi$ reproduces a static potential $V(r)$ through $\langle g|\Phi|g\rangle = V(r)$ and it was asked me to calculate the transition probability, given by a certain Hamiltonian where there is a linear coupling of the field with other stuff, that a quantum of the coherent state escapes to infinity. Of course, if I pick as an initial state a coherent state $|g\rangle$ and as a final state a less occupied coherent state $|g'\rangle$, the result vanishes since these states kill any temporal dependence of the field, and the transition in time is zero. However, it was pointed out to me that the final state misses a piece, the quanta that escaped, which should enter in the state with their own wavefunction, such as a plane wave $e^{ikx - i\omega t}$.
Then it comes my question: we are obviously working in the Heisenberg picture since the field $\Phi$ has the expansion in the usual modes multiplied by the time dependent evolution factor of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$, so how is it possible to put a time dependence in a wavefunction which is in a state of the field? My supervisor argued that this is the only way people knows to insert "by hand" something propagating in a theory that reproduces static, and thus Non Relativistic, configurations, but I miss somethign and I would like a complete explanation or a reference where this practice is well justified. If you want more infos about the background work I'll give it to you, but the very point is this freaky time depencende that seems to be necessary to have a reasonable result.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you want to do. Maybe, using math instead of words could help here. Also, a specific reference to a paper/book could help.

Comment: Ok, the point is that I want to evaluate a transition amplitude due to the presence of an interacting hamiltonian involving the field $\Phi(x)$. The initial and final states of this amplitude are two coherent state, and since from the beginning I require that $<coherent|\Phi|coherent> = V(r)$, no time dependence implies zero transition probability. My supervisor suggested that the final state should not be only a coherent state, but $<coherent|*e^{-ikx +i \omega t}$. How is it possible to have a state which is time dependent if we are working in the Heisenberg picture for the field $\Phi$?